# Azure devops build validation central repository pipeline - multiple repository

Tags: python, git, powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a question about a way to do the following in azure devops build validation pipeline.

I have azure devops with a build validation pipeline in a central repository that holds the yaml pipeline and powershell scripts to perform validation.

1 of the powershell scripts (call it script.ps1) requires the PR code directory as an argument, so it can scan to make sure files are valid (check folders for certain extensions).

will have branch build validation policies applied to all other repos in the project. (Repo 1, 2, 3 etc.) Whenever a PR is raised into the protected branch, this will trigger the build validation pipeline. the yaml will have no trigger as the build validation policy is the trigger (is my understanding).

- central repo

  - pipeline.yml
  - script.ps1
  - script2.ps1
- repo 1

  - some files and folders
- repo 2
- repo 3

  Etc

Script.ps1 -

By default when the central build validation pipeline runs it checksout self, so before I was using pre defined variables such as Agent.BuildDirectory to pass in the directory, This worked if the build validation pipeline lived within the repository of the PR for script.ps1 but this is not the case with the requirement of it living with central repository.

So how would one run a yaml pipeline from a central repo location and Checkout self and the code of the pr location so that we can pass the directory of pr repo in as an argument for a powershell script.ps1 which is from the central repository.

Thank you in advance.
Cheers!

I have tried cloning the pr repo but running into auth issues.

I'd rather use checkout yaml way if possible.

Is there a simple way to dynamically checkout the repo in yaml and pass that directory into ps script as an argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a simple way to dynamically checkout the repo in yaml and pass that directory into ps script as an argument.

Based on your requirement, you need to checkout the repo based on the PR triggered info.

You can use the [Repo resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops) in YAML pipeline to checkout multiple repo resources. And use the [condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cstages) and [Predefined variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml): **System.PullRequest.SourceRepositoryURI** to define which repo to checkout.

Here is YAML example:

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: Repo01 
    type: git
    name: Repo01
  - repository: Repo02
    type: git
    name: Repo02
  - repository: Repo03
    type: git
    name: Repo03
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- checkout: Repo01
  condition: eq(variables['System.PullRequest.SourceRepositoryURI'], 'https://orgname@dev.azure.com/orgname/projectname/_git/Repo01')
- checkout: Repo02
  condition: eq(variables['System.PullRequest.SourceRepositoryURI'], 'https://orgname@dev.azure.com/orgname/projectname/_git/Repo02')
- checkout: Repo03
  condition: eq(variables['System.PullRequest.SourceRepositoryURI'], 'https://orgname@dev.azure.com/orgname/projectname/_git/Repo03')


- task: PowerShell@2
  condition: eq(variables['System.PullRequest.SourceRepositoryURI'], 'https://orgname@dev.azure.com/orgname/projectname/_git/Repo01')
  inputs:
    filePath: 'test.ps'
    arguments: '-filepath $(build.sourcesdirectory)/Repo01'

- task: PowerShell@2
  condition: eq(variables['System.PullRequest.SourceRepositoryURI'], 'https://orgname@dev.azure.com/orgname/projectname/_git/Repo02')
  inputs:
    filePath: 'test.ps'
    arguments: '-filepath $(build.sourcesdirectory)/Repo02'

- task: PowerShell@2
  condition: eq(variables['System.PullRequest.SourceRepositoryURI'], 'https://orgname@dev.azure.com/orgname/projectname/_git/Repo03')
  inputs:
    filePath: 'test.ps'
    arguments: '-filepath $(build.sourcesdirectory)/Repo03'
```

**Note:** When we use multiple resources in YAML pipeline, it will checkout the repo files to the file path: **$(Build.sourcesdirectory)/reponame**

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I was able to use this idea to obtain the results I was after.